# Converting JSON string into date

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

I'm trying to convert the string that [this api returns](http://api.bukget.org/api2/bukkit/plugin/essentials) for date. The format is `1351993013`. I tried the following line of JS but the date is completely wrong.

```
var jsonDate = plugin.versions[0].date;
var pluginDate = new Date(jsonDate);
```

Which returns:

```
Fri Jan 16 1970
```

This is the first time I've tried to format a JSON date so it's a bit confusing. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is not a JSON-specific date, but rather a UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be seconds, and javascript uses milliseconds which would be

```
1351993013​000
```

which would give you Sunday Nov 04 2012.

in other words:

```
var jsonDate = parseInt(plugin.versions[0].date, 10) * 1000;
```

Comment: You're welcome, this date stuff can be really confusing sometimes.